# How to create a random roulette selector/roulette horizontal scrollbar? - Tkinter Python

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

So as i have already posted a few questions here, about this assignment i have to do for uni, that is about building a food recipes desktop app with Tkinter and Python. And i thought it would be nice to add some kind of a random horizontal scroll/roulette selector of recipes in this bar that i am insert at the bottom of the startpage:

Like whenever the user clicked in one of the arrows (right or left) it would roll horizontally different recipe buttons and after some secons it would stop, something like a roulette I think:
[image: Like whenever the user clicked in one of the arrows (right or left) it would roll horizontally different recipe buttons and after some secons it would stop, something like a roulette i think]

Is that even possible to make with Tkinter and Python? I have already put the recipes buttons inside a main canvas, that would hide, on its sides, the others buttons that are not appearing at the moment. And i would probably need to do some function to when either one of the arrows was clicked it would do the "random selector thing". But what do i need to have inside the function? Thank you!!

Here's the code that i have already have for the bar:

````
        self.c_randombar = Canvas(self, width=1078, height=64, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0,relief="flat", )
        self.c_randombar.place(x=181, y=906,)
        self.img_random = PhotoImage(file="assets/frame0/randomrecipe.png")
        self.c_randombar.create_image(0, 0,anchor="nw", image= self.img_random)
        #Right Arrow
        self.c_rightarrow = Canvas(self, width=81, height=64, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0,relief="flat", )
        self.c_rightarrow.place(x=1290, y=907,)
        self.img_bg_rightarrow = PhotoImage(file="assets/frame0/bg_rightarrow.png")
        self.c_rightarrow.create_image(0, 0,anchor="nw", image= self.img_bg_rightarrow)
        #---------
        self.img_rightarrow = PhotoImage(file = r"assets/frame0/button_rightarrow.png")
        self.button_rightarrow = tk.Button(self, image = self.img_rightarrow, command= lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage), relief="flat", borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0,)
        self.button_rightarrow.place(x=1289, y=906, width=81, height=64)
        #Left Arrow
        self.c_leftarrow = Canvas(self, width=81, height=64, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0,relief="flat", )
        self.c_leftarrow.place(x=71, y=907,)
        self.img_bg_leftarrow = PhotoImage(file="assets/frame0/bg_rightarrow.png")
        self.c_leftarrow.create_image(0, 0,anchor="nw", image= self.img_bg_leftarrow)
        #---------
        self.img_leftarrow = PhotoImage(file = r"assets/frame0/button_leftarrow.png")
        self.button_leftarrow = tk.Button(self, image = self.img_leftarrow, command= lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage), relief="flat", borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0,)
        self.button_leftarrow.place(x=70, y=906, width=81, height=64)
        #____________________________

        #Main Canvas for the recipes buttons
        self.c_recipes = Canvas(self, width=1074, height=60, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0,relief="flat", background="#182DEF")
        self.c_recipes.place(x=183, y=908)
        #Recipe 1
        self.c_recipe1 = Canvas(self.c_recipes, width=157, height=27, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0,relief="flat", )
        self.c_recipe1.place(x=40, y=17,)
        self.img_bg_recipe1 = PhotoImage(file="assets/frame0/Nova pasta/bg_button1.png")
        self.c_recipe1.create_image(0, 0,anchor="nw", image= self.img_bg_recipe1)
        #---------
        self.img_recipe1 = PhotoImage(file = r"assets/frame0/Nova pasta/button1.png")
        self.button_recipe1 = tk.Button(self.c_recipes, image = self.img_recipe1, command= lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage), relief="flat", borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0,activebackground="#182DEF")
        self.button_recipe1.place(x=39, y=16, width=157, height=27)
        #____________________________
        #Recipe 2
        self.c_recipe2 = Canvas(self.c_recipes, width=256, height=27, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0,relief="flat", )
        self.c_recipe2.place(x=340, y=17,)
        self.img_bg_recipe2 = PhotoImage(file="assets/frame0/Nova pasta/bg_button2.png")
        self.c_recipe2.create_image(0, 0,anchor="nw", image= self.img_bg_recipe2)
        #---------
        self.img_recipe2 = PhotoImage(file = r"assets/frame0/Nova pasta/button2.png")
        self.button_recipe2 = tk.Button(self.c_recipes, image = self.img_recipe2, command= lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage), relief="flat", borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0,activebackground="#182DEF")
        self.button_recipe2.place(x=339, y=16, width=256, height=27)
        #____________________________
        #Recipe 3
        self.c_recipe3 = Canvas(self.c_recipes, width=296, height=27, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0,relief="flat", )
        self.c_recipe3.place(x=739, y=17,)
        self.img_bg_recipe3 = PhotoImage(file="assets/frame0/Nova pasta/bg_button3.png")
        self.c_recipe3.create_image(0, 0,anchor="nw", image= self.img_bg_recipe3)
        #---------
        self.img_recipe3 = PhotoImage(file = r"assets/frame0/Nova pasta/button3.png")
        self.button_recipe3 = tk.Button(self.c_recipes, image = self.img_recipe3, command= lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage), relief="flat", borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0,activebackground="#182DEF")
        self.button_recipe3.place(x=738, y=16, width=296, height=27)
        #____________________________```

Forever thankful!!
````

Comment: _"Is that even possible to make with Tkinter and Python? "_ - yes, it absolutely is possible.

Comment: We can't run your code. It's incomplete and depends on external images. Since the feature you're asking about doesn't rely on images, it would help if you created a [mcve] that didn't rely on images.